# select range of dates from xarray DataArray using isel

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm working on subsetting NASA DAYMET data based on a range of dates - specifically, I'm trying to automate the subsetting of 20 years worth of daily climate data, but am only interested in the summer months of each year. I've managed to get my code to partially work but it is still having trouble with updating for each year. i.e. if four years of data are specified, the same year's worth of daily data is output four different times, with only the year in the title of the plot updated. The resulting plots have updated years in the title but the data itself is only from one year.

The loop currently outputs each day from the summer months (June-August), but the output data is not updating the year correctly. I have been working with isel function from xarray as it has an add-on that adds the ability to work with raster data.

I'm inclined to believe that the issue resides with this line in the second nested loop:
 `prcp_1day_export = prcp_clip.isel(time=spec_day)`

The end result of the code should be a matplotlib plot and a .tif file with the original data that has been clipped to my study area.

```
for spec_year in range(2000, 2003):
        print("year = " + str(spec_year))
        start_date = dt.datetime(spec_year, 6, 1) # specify your own start date
        end_date = dt.datetime(spec_year, 7, 1)  # specify your end start date
        beg_day = (start_date - dt.datetime(spec_year, 1, 1)).days
        end_day = beg_day + 92 
        print(start_date)
        print(end_date)
        print(beg_day)
        print(end_day)
        
        for spec_day in range(beg_day, end_day):
            # rename and export
#             print(str(spec_day)) #spec_day will be the value to use to specify what time equals a particular day
            # The line below is the likely result of the inaccurate specification of year when automating the subset.
            prcp_1day_export = prcp_clip.isel(time=spec_day)
            print(str(prcp_1day_export))
            prcp_1day_export.rio.to_raster("prcp_1day_export" + "_" + str(spec_day) + "_" + str(spec_year) + ".tif")
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,10))
            prcp_1day_export.plot(ax=ax, robust=True, cbar_kwargs={'label': 'mm/day'})
            ga_shape_lcc.plot(ax = ax, color = 'none', edgecolor = 'red')
            fig.savefig("prcp_1day_export" + "_" + str(spec_day) + "_" + str(spec_year) + ".png")
            

print("Finished")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you have a good question here, but I'm a little confused what it is you're trying to do. Your question title mentions selecting a range of dates, but the code is clearly trying to select one date at a time. Also, you say the year is not being updated correctly, but I don't see where `prcp_clip` is defined or how `spec_year` is used, since you're selecting from the data using the day of year only. Can you clarify the question a bit? See this guide on [how to ask a question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, is there a reason you can't use [`sel`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sel.html)? xarray handles selecting based on dates natively, e.g. `prcp_clip.sel(time=slice(start_date, end_date))` or `for day in pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D'): prcp_clip.sel(time=day)`

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for the warm welcome! I apologize if my wording was a bit unclear before. To clarify, I am essentially trying to subset DAYMET data from 2000-2020 for the purposes of creating a time-series analysis of precipitiation during the summer months. Currently, my code is producing daily data, but my end goal is to calculate summary statistics for each summer season to find the areas of highest precipitation within my study area. As for the previous lines of code I neglected to include, there is a jupyter notebook on my github under the DAYMET analysis repo.

Comment: I didn't use ```isel``` for any particular reason as I've been following along with a tutorial from NASA's ORNL on how to work with the data. I essentially followed exactly what the original authors did with one addition - the loop that doesn't work properly.

Comment: https://github.com/SamShuster97/DAYMET_ANALYSIS_2021/blob/main/1_daymetv4_discovery_access_subsetting.ipynb

Comment: got it. did you try the code I suggested using sel? otherwise, we don't have all the info we'd need to debug this *within the question* - see this guide on creating a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I was all set to but now I'm suddenly receiving this error when I try to fetch the data from ORNL's data server: ```HTTPSConnectionPool(host='thredds.daac.ornl.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /thredds/dodsC/ornldaac/1840/daymet_v4_daily_na_prcp_2015.nc.dds (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))``` Will give it a shot once I figure out what's going on to cause the error.